# Laplace Transform of unknown functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I don't know how to go about solving these questions the second one seems to want integration by parts but I don't know how that will work out, an the first one seems to need the definition of Laplace transforms but I don't see how that will work out.

Show that for any function f(t) for which the Laplace transform
$L [f(t)] = F(s)$ exists, $L[tf(t)] = −F'(s)$

Solve the equation for $x(t)$ :
$$\int_0^{t}(x(τ )(t− τ ))dτ = t^4$$

Comment: So your equation looks like a convolution $x \ast h(t)$ with $h(t) = t$ and $x(t)$ causal. But because of the non-causality of $h(t)$, for solving it I need the Fourier transform (of distributions... more or less the bilateral Laplace transform) . Are you sure it is  $\int_0^\infty$ and not $\int_0^t$ ???

Comment: Your correct thanks.

Comment: So if $y(t) = x \ast h(t)$ then $Y(s) = \ ?$  (here $h(t) = t \ 1_{t > 0}$)

Comment: Wait what I'm confused.

Comment: $y(t) =\int_0^{t}x(\tau )(t− \tau)d\tau = x \ast h(t)$ (where $\ast $ is the convolution), $Y(s) = \int_0^\infty y(t) e^{-st} dt = \ ?$

Comment: How would that help?Thanks.

Comment: You don't know the formula for the Laplace transform of a convolution product ?

Comment: No I do , but I don't understand how that would help? Because aren't you then taking an intergral of an intergral. Okay, I will try.

Comment: Do it and you'll see (that the LT transforms convolution into products is its main purpose, letting use solve many differential equations)

Comment: So you are saying don't use convolution of intergral use the definition directly?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Note that $x(t)$ is the unknown, under LT it becomes $X(s)$.

Comment: Cause it seems to me that you are instead saying use the definition of Laplace transformation an the integrand would be X(t)te^st

Comment: ??? let as usual $X(s) = \int_0^\infty x(t) e^{-st} dt$ and $H(s) = \int_0^\infty h(t) e^{-st} dt$ then with $y(t) = x \ast h(t)$ what do you get for  $Y(s) = \int_0^\infty y(t) e^{-st} dt$ ???

Comment: Shouldn't there be a t there?Can you just show the setup, this isn't a home work questiin I'm reviewing the professor old exams for my final.

Comment: $Y(s) = \ ? $ u r boring

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: $Y(s) = H(x) X(s)$ and since $H(s) = \int_0^\infty h(t) e^{-st} dt = \int_0^\infty t e^{-st} dt  = \frac{-1}{s^2}$ you get $Y(s) = -\frac{X(s)}{s^2}$. But you also know that $y(t) = t^4$ so $Y(s) = L[t^4](s)$ and overall $X(s) = -s^2 L[t^4]$.. What is the Laplace transform of $t^4$ ??

Comment: I see thanks. An the other question is a similar proof.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by using the property of convolution theorem.

Following are the steps to solve these type of problems:

First, take the Laplace transform on both the sides.
Then, on the left hand side apply convolution theorem in which $f(t)=x(t)$ and $g (t) = t$.  After calculating $x(s)$, take the inverse transform.